# Need help creating a routing rule

Tags: networking, wired-networking

My 14.04 LTS ubuntu box has 2 active network connections. the default gateway is the hardwired eth0 (192.168.1.x) going to my cable modem.

The wireless connection (wlan0 at 192.168.0.x) is to a cellular access point to Sprint LTE gateway, and I want to ssh with the -b option to bind to the wireless connection and with socks proxy port forwarding going through the Sprint network, not through my cable modem. (I couldn't figure out how to run a separate 2nd sshd process for the wireless connection)

What routing rules are required to route the ssh socks proxy traffic through the wireless connection rather than the default gateway on eth0?

Comment: Just for clarification.
When do you not want to use default gw?

Is it based upon IP or Interface specific

Answer (score -1):

You aren't looking to add a route.

You first mention ssh, and then sshd.

SSH is the client, that connects to the SSHd daemon.

For ssh (as a client) you can bind to an interface using -b. This will then use the default gateway for that interface, unless a more specific route is set.

This is as simple as passing the binding IP when running the ssh command

```
ssh -b 192.168.0.<IP> user@server.to.connect.to
```

For SSHd (The SSH server) you'll want to edit the config for the server, and look for the lines specifying a ListenAddress - by default it'll generally listen on *all* interfaces. Normally this file is /etc/ssh/sshd_config however it varies by distribution.

```
ListenAddress host|IPv4_addr|IPv6_addr
```

So like this:

```
ListenAddress 192.168.0.<IP>
```

**Note**: If you set a listen address, it'll ONLY listen on this address, add as many listen addresses (on new lines with the ListenAddress) as you need.

Once you've made these changes, be sure to restart SSHd in the fashion your distribution chooses.